# Measure associated to a top-degree differential form (not necessarily a volume form) on a K-analytic manifold (K a local field)

Tags: measure-theory, differential-forms

Suppose $K$ is a non-Archimedian local field and suppose $\omega$ is a top-degree differential form on a compact $K$-analytic manifold $M$ of dimension $n$. It is possible to construct a Borel measure on $M$, denoted $\mu_{\omega}$, essentially by writing
$$\mu_{\omega}(A) = \int_A|f|d\mu $$
locally. That is, on a coordinate patch $U$ on which $\omega = fdx_1\wedge...\wedge x_n$ we define it as such (we can make sense of this by integrating on polydisks and applying Caratheodory's extension theorem) with respect to the Haar measure $\mu$ on $K^n$. This doesn't depend on the choice of coordinates because of the standard change of variables formula.

One element of this construction is that an arbitrary Borel set $A$ can be written as a disjoint union of Borel sets which are contained in a coordinate patch on which we know how to integrate Borel sets. This leads me to some questions:

1. Does this extend to $K$-analytic manifolds which are not compact? I explicitly used compactness to show that I can cover $M$ with disjoint coordinate patches. (I did the obvious and used clopenness of the basis to iteratively transform a finite clopen cover into a finite disjoint clopen cover. This does not work if $M$ is not compact.) I do not believe it should, but I cannot come up with a counterexample.
2. I do not see why this construction fails for real manifolds. I have a (very strong) suspicion that this is defining a density on a manifold. In fact, I am nearly certain that this is simply integrating the density $|\omega|$. Can anyone confirm this? The only fact specific to $K$-analytic manifolds that I used is this ability to write a Borel set as a disjoint union of Borel sets in coordinate patches. That being said:
3. I believe this requirement that Borel sets are disjoint unions of Borel sets in coordinate patches is actually a red herring. Is it simply true that one can do this? (I don't see how to do this if the patches are not disjoint.) Otherwise, is there a work-around?

Comment: This procedure certainly works for real manifolds, and compactness is not needed (all we need is that the manifold can be covered by countably many charts). Indeed, this is a very standard way of showing how a (non-negative Borel-measurable) scalar density $\rho$ on $M$ induces a positive "Lebesgue measure" $\lambda_{\rho}$ on $M$. For example, the usual example of such scalar densities is by taking "absolute values" of top-degree forms $\rho=|\omega|$.

Comment: The standard application for this is when you have a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, then one considers a "standard" volume scalar density $\rho_g$, which gives rise to the measure $\lambda_{\rho_g}$, which for a Borel set $E$ lying inside a chart $(U,\alpha)$ is simply $\lambda_{\rho_g}(E)=\int_{\alpha[E]}\sqrt{|\det g_{ij}(x)|}\,dx$ (and this procedure works on non-orientable manifolds as well).

Comment: Indeed. It has also occurred to me how to work around this Borel set issue. If you have a Borel set $A$ that lives inside two patches $U$ and $V$, you can write $A$ as the disjoint union of the Borel sets $A \cap U$ and $A \cap (V\setminus U)$. You can iterate this process over a countable cover and you will still get a Borel set. To be precise, if $U_i$ is a countable cover, we can write $A$ as the disjoint union of $A \cap U_1$, $A \cap (U_2 \setminus U_1)$, $A \cap (U_3 \setminus (U_1 \cup U_2))$ etc. etc.

Comment: It follows that compactness is not necessary. To make it obvious, as long as we can write any Borel set $A$ as a disjoint union of countably many Borel sets $A_i$ which are contained in charts, we find $\mu(A)$ by summing $\mu(A_i)$. (Of course, the measure of $A$ can be infinite.) This fails when you can't cover the manifold by countably many charts, since then it may be the case that some Borel set can't be split up nicely.

Comment: I think an example of this occurs with $M$ equal to the disjoint union of uncountably many $\mathbb{R}^n$. Pick the standard top-degree form (i.e. $\omega = dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n$ on each connected component). Take $A$ to be the set of all the origins. It is Borel (closed, even). But no countable collection of patches can cover $A$ (think ccc), therefore we cannot assign a measure to $A$ through the above process (although we might all agree that the measure should be 0). Maybe this is not the best example, since the value $\mu(A)$ is obvious, but I don't have a better example.

Comment: Sure, though usually one assumes second countability of manifolds, hence we have an atlas with countably many charts (and usually if we have Hausdorffness in the definition of a manifold, then we can even use a partition of unity argument... though I've never really liked this approach for defining the measure). Also, without having a countable atlas, even if we somehow manage to get a measure it is very likely not going to be $\sigma$-finite. So, the usual fubini, Radon-Nikodym etc etc fail. So this is a bad situation topologically and measure-theoretically too, which I'd like to avoid :)